# printf specify integer format string for float

Tags: c, casting, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 5;
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output:

```
0
```

Why is the output zero?

Comment: `#include <conio.h>` removed because not needed - other cleanups too.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't print 5 because the compiler does not know to automatically cast to an integer.  You need to do `(int)a` yourself.

That is to say,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
float a=5;
printf("%d",(int)a);
}
```

correctly outputs 5.

Compare that program with

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_int(int x)
{
printf("%d\n", x);
}
void main()
{
float a=5;
print_int(a);
}
```

where the compiler directly knows to cast the float to an int, due to the declaration of `print_int`.

Comment: Specifically, it doesn't know to automatically cast to an integer in a variadic function, but that's rather hard to explain to the beginner, particularly since it sure looks like the C compiler should know the types involved.

Comment: Besides the variadic-ness, knowing what type to cast would require the compiler to parse the string passed to printf and deduce what type a is supposed to be. GCC can easily handle a constant "%d\n" and warn you when passed `-Wall`, but good luck when the string isn't hard-coded into the program!

Comment: @MarkRushakoff Reasonable programmers don't use non-constant format strings, since they introduce a security issue.

Answer (score 14):

`%d` format specifier can only be used with values of type `int`. You are passing a `double` (which `float` will be implicitly converted to). The resultant behavior is undefined. There no answer to "why it prints 0?" question. Anything can be printed. In fact, anything can happen.

P.S.

1. That's `int main`, not `void main`.
2. There's no such header as `conio.h` in standard C.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that printf() is passed a double.  I fixed the code to remove the superfluous and irrelevant `#include <conio.h>`.

Answer (score 7):

You should either cast it to an int to use %d, or use a format string to display the float with no decimal precision:

```
int main() {
  float a=5;
  printf("%d",(int)a); // This casts to int, which will make this work
  printf("%.0f",a); // This displays with no decimal precision
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `%f` instead of `%d` - `%d` is just for integers while `%f` is for floating point:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  float a=5;
  printf("%f",a);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a different formatting string, just have a look at
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

printf("%f", a);

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use %f for printing a float value.

eg

```
float a=5;
printf("%f",a);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other people said, you need to use `%f` in the format string or convert `a` to an int.

But I want to point out that your compiler, probably, knows about `printf()`'s format string and can tell you you're using it wrong. My compiler, with the appropriate invocation (`-Wall` includes `-Wformat`), says this:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc -Wformat tmp.c
tmp.c: In function ‘main’:
tmp.c:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’

$ /usr/bin/gcc -Wall tmp.c
tmp.c: In function ‘main’:
tmp.c:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’

$
```

Oh, and one more thing: you should include '\n' in the `printf()` to ensure the output is sent to the output device.

```
printf("%d\n", a);
/*        ^^ */
```

or use `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()`.