# Can anyone explain the output

Tags: c, floating-point, double, output, undefined-behavior

If I try to print a `float` as an `int`, this code:

```
main () {                         
    float a = 6.8f;                      
    printf("%d", a);                      
}
```

prints 1073741824, while this code:

```
main () {            
    float a = 9.5f;           
    printf("%d", a);            
}
```

prints 0.

Is the output undefined? Also when is `%f` used with integer and `%d` used with double?

Comment: output is garbage or undefined operation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [print the float value in integer in C language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632080/print-the-float-value-in-integer-in-c-language)

Comment: Also calling a function that accepts a variable number of arguments (`printf()`) without a prototype in scope is UB. Use `#include <stdio.h>` for the proper prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only the output, but the entire program has undefined behavior, since type of the value you are passing to `printf()` does not match the type the format string expects.

Comment: Even the act of *compiling* that source invokes UB :)

Answer (score 2):

From the C99 standard section *7.19.6.1 The fprintf function*:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

`%d` expects an `int`, not a `float`, so the program has undefined behaviour (including the output).

Answer (score 1):

As described  in previous answers if the print format doesn't match the type passed, it shows undefined behavior.

If you want to view integer as float u need to typecast it.

```
int j = 5;
printf("%f",(float)(j));
```

This will print output as 5.0 ie as a floating digit number

Answer (score 0):

The C Standard says that the printf format must match the type passed in. If it doesn't, the behavior is expressly undefined:

C99, 7.19.6.1 # 9 (fprintf)

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.239) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.